# Openlayers: Add a solid coloured layer as overlay

Tags: javascript, node.js, overlay, openlayers

I want to give two points (GPS coordinates) as input (e.g. left top corner and bottom right corner) and add a layer where only this region is fully visible. The rest should be filled with a solid color and semi transparent. Should look something like this:

[image]

Im new to Openlayers and cant find an example... I found this example to add overlays but it didn't really help here:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overlay.html

Any idea on which function / part of the library is necessary to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a polygon covering the view extent with a hole for your specified extent.  Then display it in the base layers vector context

```
import "ol/ol.css";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import OSM from "ol/source/OSM";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import View from "ol/View";
import { fromLonLat, transformExtent } from "ol/proj";
import { getVectorContext } from "ol/render";
import { fromExtent } from "ol/geom/Polygon";
import { Style, Fill } from "ol/style";

var extent = transformExtent([10, 53, 20, 57], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");

var osmLayer = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM()
});

osmLayer.on("postrender", function (event) {
  var vectorContext = getVectorContext(event);
  vectorContext.setStyle(
    new Style({
      fill: new Fill({
        color: "rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.25)"
      })
    })
  );
  var polygon = fromExtent(map.getView().getProjection().getExtent());
  polygon.appendLinearRing(fromExtent(extent).getLinearRing(0));
  vectorContext.drawGeometry(polygon);
});

var map = new Map({
  layers: [osmLayer],
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat([15, 55]),
    zoom: 5
  })
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sun-qnezt?file=/main.js

or in a separate vector layer above the base layer

```
var polygon = fromExtent(map.getView().getProjection().getExtent());
polygon.appendLinearRing(fromExtent(extent).getLinearRing(0));
var feature = new Feature({geometry: polygon});

var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
    feature: [feature]
  }),
  style: new Style({
    fill: new Fill({
      color: "rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.25)"
    })
  })
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to define it as one layer without the need to constantly update it? I have yet another "postrender" method which updates points coming from a GeoJSON on the map... therefore the question is whether it would be enough to define the whole polygon as a layer once and "never" touch it again (same which goes for the base OSM tile layer)?

Comment: Yes, it can be done as a separate vector layer, although it might not synchronise as smoothly when zooming in/out, and if your extent did change you would have to update the geometry of the polygon feature.

Comment: There is a typo. VectorLayer.feature -> VectorLayer.features

Comment: Is there a way to have these features into the multi-worlds mode? I have to keep using ol3 (for a legacy application) and I'm try to understand if there is a way to have the  multi-worlds on this version as well. 
Basically, using this example, if you try to pan continuously around the world, after the deadline you will see another planeisphere without this layer.

Comment: vector context does not wrap automatically, you must set the feature geometries to match the frame state, and translate into the next world if necessary https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-jasper-qj9nrk?file=/main.js